# Facial features of image uploaded using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, face-recognition

I want to make an online app, in which the user can upload an image of himself and the application will give hime some statistics for his facial features in order for him to search to which celebrity the user is alike. I don't want to use OpenCV for example cause my client server doesn't support this. I would like to do that with Javascript. For example I would like something like this but with uploading an image: [Example_1](http://auduno.github.io/clmtrackr/example.html) or this which is exactly what I want to do: [Example_2](http://betaface.com/demo.html). Is there any way I can do what I want with just Javascript and if there are other ways please do not hesitate to tell me about them. Thanks for the help.

Comment: this isn't google...that's where you need to look. Questions looking for resources are off topic

Comment: @charlietfl Well as always I do my research before posting a question here but I couldn't find what I want, so I decided to ask for info here. I'm sorry if the question is off-topic but I'm pretty sure that a lot of people will have the same question and cant find the information that they want. I don't want any code but just if there is a library or something else which I can use to do what I want. Thanks for the comment and again I'm really sorry if the question is off-topic.